# LinkButton's OnClick does not fire in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, onclick, asplinkbutton

The following works just fine in Chrome.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbEdit" OnClick="lbEdit_Click">
    <button type="button" class="edit">
         Edit
    </button>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And here is the CSS for button and its subclass.

```
button
{    
    padding: 3px;
}
button.edit 
{
    background:#3f6096;
    border:none;
    font:10px verdana;
    color:#fff;
    width:71px;
    margin-top:3px;
}
```

As you can see, nothing special; just colors and beautiful things.
I click on the blue Edit button and it fires the OnClick postback just fine.... in Chrome!
But if I do the same in IE8, it just does nothing; doesn't even detect a click.

To help pinpoint the problem, I removed the  tag and kept just the word "Edit", and it works just fine in IE8 as a simple underlined link; the postback fires.

So, Why can't IE8 accept anything within LinkButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use a LinkButton if you need to handle a postback and look like a button at the same time?  Why not make it just a Button?  It seems to me that the only reason to use one over the other is appearance.  Functionally, they're both supposed to trigger a postback.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see your answer before I posted. +1!

Comment: That did it for me; not sure why I started with LinkButton.  Switching to Button and using the same CSS for it worked just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran into a similar situation where a `LinkButton` didn't seem to want to proceed with firing its `OnClick` event after using an `OnClientClick` for a javascript confirmation dialog. Strangely just changing to a regular ASP `Button` worked around this and now the `OnClick` fires in IE. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing isn't something you are *supposed* to do, but I would say that IE is probably the one behaving closest to 'correctly' here.

You should not nest button elements inside other elements that provide links. You can simply remove the `button` from inside the `LinkButton`, attach the OnClick to it instead, make the styling work, and it'll be good.

The reason I say I think IE is behaving closer to 'correctly' is because it's doing what you have defined on the innermost tag; which is nothing. (you have not attached any actions to the `button` element, in actuality). But really, it's not something you should do in HTML anyway, as I don't think the behavior is defined in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve here?

You have a server-side link button, with a nested HTML button?

A LinkButton is useful when you want a **hyperlink** to be able to perform a postback.

Did you have a look at the rendered HTML? I don't know if having a button inside an anchor tag is even valid HTML.

If you want the postback to be handled by a particular server-side event, just use an ASP:Button.

If you dont, just use a regular HTML button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CssClass:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opciones">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Hola!" CommandName="Deshabilitar" 
        CssClass="btn btn-primary"
        CommandArgument='<%# Item.Id %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```